# Looking for the title of an anime movie I saw in the 80s

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm from the Netherlands and we used to have filmnet at home, a paid movie channel. They would always show anime movies in the weekends.
I think this movie was on in 1985/ 1986, something like that.

I only remember that the protagonists were a boy and a girl, possibly siblings. There was a war and huge stone or metal boulders. In the end the girl dies or ascends (?) while the boy stays behind. The reason he stays behind is because he is mentally not yet evolved enough to ascend.

The boy has brown hair. The two were young, possibly 13-14? There might have been a comical pet dog.

At the same time, Filmnet aired Magical Princess Minky Momo and the Fountain of Youth, but the setting and the atmosphere of both movies were very different.

Pretty vague, I know. But this is all I remember. I'll continue to add details as they come back to me, but as I said in the comments, I was 6,7 at the time and my memories are obscure. I wish I had a mind castle like Sherlock Holmes... :)

Comment: Do you have anything else to give us to work this?

Comment: Nope, this is it .. unfortunately... that's why it's so difficult to trace :)

Comment: Can you comment on the setting at all? Apparent timeframe? Did they have any special abilities? Magical pets? Otherwordly animals? The apparent age of the boy/girl (very young, or adult-height) Anything can help.

Comment: Questions can trigger memories so please, ask on! The boy has brown hair. The two were young, possibly 13-14? 
I was 6,7 years old at the time so my memory is really fuzzy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had an amazing brain wave... I searched for movies that were dubbed around the same time by the same company that did the magical princess Gigi (because I saw Minky Momo under that title) and I found it!
Here is a [link to the ending](http://youtu.be/-dhPrjxbcFo)

It is called Birth. it is also known as The World of the Talisman and Planet Busters, but as far as I gathered the original title is Birth.

Thanks for thinking along and sorry to bother you :) But I'm not sure if I would have had my brain wave if it hadn't been for this website :)