# 80s (or earlier) anime with Cyclops-like sentinels shooting lasers out of their eyes, and finding a wepaon in a long-lost underground city

Tags: story-identification, anime

I watched this anime in the late 80s.

The protagonists may have been kids (perhaps a boy and a girl).  I seem to recall them either crash-landing on an unknown planet, and constantly trying to outrun large spherical (probably red-coloured) sentinels that were trying to kill them.  I think the sentinels were reminiscent of [Cyclops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclops_(Marvel_Comics)), with lasers that were coming out of their eyes.

In their quest, they understand the history and why they were being hunted they discover a long-lost underground city, with no one alive. It culminates in finding a room/hall with a weapon (looked like a rocket launcher or something).  Leading up to a weapon was a dead body whose last moments may have been trying to reach it.

They get the weapon, but the video tape ended.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18798/looking-for-the-title-of-an-anime-movie-i-saw-in-the-80s

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are describing the 1984 OAV "[Birth](https://www.animenewsnetwork.co.uk/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=2662)."  The ending isn't very far beyond what you've already recalled.

> Nam's home planet of Aqualoid has become a barren wasteland since the invasion of the Inorganics. However, he soon discovers SHADE, a sword with the power to control Aqualoid and give power back to its people. There's just one problem, every Inorganic on the planet wants to see the sword destroyed and Nam and his friends dead.

Comment: It is also known as The World of the Talisman and Planet Busters, but as far as I gathered the original title is Birth. I posted a link to the answered question I asked some time ago, it was about the same movie