# Anime style cartoon - 4 characters on a planet with giant oval floating robots looking for them - 1989 or before

Tags: story-identification, robots, anime

I have been trying to find a cartoon I watched as a kid. It was shown on Sky Movies (UK) in 1989 or 1990 in the kids cartoons slot on Sky Analogue. It featured a team of four characters, possibly starting out in a spaceship, that land on a planet. The planet was empty except for sand and various buildings. There were one or two giant (70ft or more) oval shaped robots that the characters were hiding from. The robots were primary colors (red and blue I think), with heads that turned constantly looking for the characters. It was anime in appearance (certainly looked different from the Danger Mouse/Hanna Barbera cartoons that were usually shown on TV at the time) with lots of fast paced running sequences. One of the main characters had a cigar that stayed in the air when he spoke (shouted really). Any ideas??

Comment: Is this the same cartoon as described starting at [post #6615 in this forum thread](http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=476265&show=6600)?

Comment: duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18798/looking-for-the-title-of-an-anime-movie-i-saw-in-the-80s

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to finding another person who asked for an ID of an anime matching yours on [Quora.com](http://www.quora.com/What-is-this-old-anime-movie), Looks like I managed to locate it.

[Birth aka Planet Busters aka The World of the Talisman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birth_%28anime%29)(1984).

Plot Summary(from wiki):

> It is based on a far futuristic planet where four mercenaries try to
>   find the ultimate weapon which can either save humanity or destroy it.
>   Against mechas and strange races, together they sweep the vast planet
>   to reach their goal.
>
> Aqualoid was a prosperous planet, but an attack from a mysterious life
>   force, the Inorganics, transforms it into a post-apocalyptic shell of
>   its former self. When Nam finds a mysterious sword, he is suddenly the
>   object of a planet-wide chase. With the Inorganics closing in, will
>   Nam and his friends discover the secret of the sword and save their
>   world? Or will they destroy Aqualoid in favor of a new Birth?

[Site with long recap/review + pics](http://www.anime-games.co.uk/VHS/anime/talisman.php)

> It follows the lives of brother and sister **Namu Shurugi and Rasa
>   Jupiter** whose peaceful existence on the planet Aquaroid is destroyed
>   by an invading android race known as the Inorganics. During their
>   battle for survival the two meet **Bao and Kim** two treasure hunters
>   seeking a legendary Talisman which is hidden somewhere on the planet
>   and will bestow the owner with godlike powers. The four of them are
>   chased across the planet by the unrelenting Inorganics and eventually
>   it is revealed that there is more to this simple quest than it first
>   seemed.

Picture of the four leads- Bao Luzen (far left) has the cigar:
[image]

---

**Youtube upload of the whole movie in 6 parts:**
[Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WMdRjPyjY8s&list=PLztcPnMm0jXynvfuOI5rlRecRa5Ls8oSO)
[Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1mgHLbqxjs4&list=PLztcPnMm0jXynvfuOI5rlRecRa5Ls8oSO&index=2)
[Part 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BW3HR0jfUsc&list=PLztcPnMm0jXynvfuOI5rlRecRa5Ls8oSO&index=3) (there's a green bot here, and the red and blue bots are "activated" at the end)

**Part 4 (red and blue bots here):**

[Part 5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgPm48QW66g&index=5&list=PLztcPnMm0jXynvfuOI5rlRecRa5Ls8oSO)
[Part 6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJhqDHo0RMg&index=6&list=PLztcPnMm0jXynvfuOI5rlRecRa5Ls8oSO)

Comment: Thanks Trish, that's it!! Amazing :o) I've been searching for the answer for that for years! Now to kick back and watch it again :o) Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Your video link is dead.