# Old anime show with pirate, princess, and boy

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember an old anime show that involved a girl pirate, a princess with two robots (I think they were red and blue) and a guy. I'm pretty sure the guy could jump through a portal to get to different locations. The pirate and princess were both in love with him. I think it used to be on cartoon network but I could be completely wrong. I can not remember what it is called, and have been trying to figure it out for awhile now.

Comment: Possible dupe of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79775/anime-style-cartoon-4-characters-on-a-planet-with-giant-oval-floating-robots-l

Comment: @Valorum Cross duping counts on story ID questions with different details?

Comment: @Terriblefan - If the answers are the same, then yes.

Comment: But we would have to have accepted answers for both (checked or commented) to close it, of course.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like [Tenchi Muyo](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiIsYG3vLXRAhVC8GMKHY1QBWgQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FTenchi_Muyo!&usg=AFQjCNFHzYvn2wEDR5Lp4W2G-HzUW9frng&bvm=bv.142059868,d.cGc). It first aired in Japan in 1992. Then in the U.S. on Cartoon Network back in 1993.

This is one of the early harem type animes where the majority of the female characters are after one reluctant guy, in this case Tenchi.

The female pirate is Ryoko Hakubi, who can fly, create light sabres and shoot beams out of her hands and phase thru matter.

While the other female with the two robots is Ayeka Jurai, Prinicess of the Jurai Empire.  The two robot logs are her bodyguards, Azaka and Kamidake. One is marked with Blue kanji and the other with a red kanji character.

As for the boy Tenchi, he himself isn't able to create portals, but one of the other girls in the series, Washuu, can create sub-dimensions and portals easily.

Besides the original OVAs there was also a TV series and a Movie.