# Animation film with giant sphere-like bad "robot"

Tags: story-identification, anime, robots

Asking community to help identify anime (animation film) from my childhood.

By the style of that animated cartoon it seems like it was from 70s or 80s, and it had Japanese picture style to it. I saw it approx. in 1994 on some local TV channel that does not exist any more. I think it called "KS video".

All I remember is that there was a boy/man hiding in some buildings or ruined sky scrapers in partially destroyed city. It was dark. He was hiding from a giant hovering robot-like thing, that looked like a giant (as tall as buildings) metal sphere with a hood-like "head" and no legs or arms. This robot was slowly hovering, scanning with creepy noise for any movement, and firing a destructive beam out of his "head". Under that hood there was no face but something glowing red or orange. If I remember correctly there was 2 of that "robots" slowly destroying the city.

Unfortunately I don't remember any more details, I have seen this on TV long time ago, but I remember that it was cool and scary animation cartoon.

I have created a rough image of how this robot looked like:

[image: Remembered rending of the robot]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Comment: The only thing I can think it might be is Thundarr the Barbarian https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundarr_the_Barbarian but I can't find any evidence at the moment.

Comment: Thundarr looks more fantasy alike, but that cartoon looked more like sci-fi

Comment: Thundarr is a post-apocalyptic fantasy I suppose, it was just the only thing I could think of that might possibly match. I wasn't confident enough to make it an answer.

Comment: It's not [_The Incredibles_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6IBtF9CVoIg) is it!?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot IKR. That was my first thought too. Unfortunately, they were playing on the trope, not the other way around

Comment: haha, nono :) The Incredibles are too young :) I saw that cartoon that I described around 10 years before The Incredibles.

Comment: It's not your thing, but if you like destructive robot spheres, totally check out *[The Transformers: The Movie (1986)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Transformers:_The_Movie)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found it, it seems that someone here also was looking for this cartoon. I found it in suggestion section here: [Anime style cartoon - 4 characters on a planet with giant oval floating robots looking for them - 1989 or before](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/79775/58193)

Cartoon is called [*Birth* aka Planet Busters aka The World of the Talisman(1984)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birth_%28anime%29).

> Aqualoid was a prosperous planet, but an attack from a mysterious life force, the Inorganics, transforms it into a post-apocalyptic shell of its former self. When Nam finds a mysterious sword, he is suddenly the object of a planet-wide chase. With the Inorganics closing in, will Nam and his friends discover the secret of the sword and save their world? Or will they destroy Aqualoid in favor of a new Birth?

Comment: +1 Thank you. I've been looking for this film for 5+ years. You made my day!

Answer (score 2):

It might possibly be the French animated science fiction movie ***La planète sauvage*** (1973), released in English as *Fantastic Planet*. The Earth has long ago been conquered by giant, blue-skinned humanoids that keep people as pets. Our hero escapes to a ruined city in the wilderness inhabited by wild humans, and he uses his knowledge of alien technology to help these people survive and even strike back at some aliens that abuse humans. The aliens respond by sending a series of destructive machines into the wilderness to exterminate the human pests. I believe one of these could be the beam robot you describe, though I can't find a clip or image to prove it.

[image]

It is a very strange and often poetic movie. You can see the trailer [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZkIAkDsiUoo).

Comment: no, definitely not this one. Giant robot in what I saw was really like a huge metal hoovering sphere, and its head did not contain any facial features - it was just something glowing red or orange under the hood-like head.

Comment: The blue person in the picture is not the robot, but one of the aliens. As I said, I couldn't find an image of the robot.

Comment: unfortunately no, that is not the one I looked for

Answer (score 2):

Could it possibly be *Heavy Metal*?

[image]

[*Heavy Metal* (1981) at IMDb](http://imdb.com/title/tt0082509/)

I based this answer more on the image the OP provided and didn't consider the plot as much as I should have. As pointed out in the comments this ship does not destroy buildings.

Comment: This is perilously close to a link-only answer, and further, I don't recall any image of that *ship* causing damage, other than sparks and scrape marks when the drugged-up pilots landed while under "fly as if you're sober" procedure.

Comment: @ZeissIkon You're right it is rather a flimsy answer, it was the vague similarity of the images (which is very vague) that prompted me. I can delete the answer if it is unsuitable.

Comment: No, "improve, don't remove."  Go ahead and flesh it out with information about the ship in that image and how it could be mistaken for the robot with the beam, or conflated with something else in the film (like the green orb) to produce that kind fo memory.

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me to some extent of a segment from [*Nausicaa of the Valley of the Wind*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nausica%C3%A4_of_the_Valley_of_the_Wind_(film)), a Studio Ghibli animated film released in Japanese in 1984, with a heavily edited English dub in the mid-1980s, and a full redub released in 2005.

The segment I refer to has a giant war robot hatching from an immense egg; it scans with a single large eye, as I recall, and fires a what amounts to an atomic fireball from where it's mouth should be (it's been some years since I've seen the film).  The combination of the egg with the editing of the fighting scene could have led to a partial memory of a near-spherical hovering robot with an eye on top -- especially because the title character was, at the same time, riding a even larger insectoid (like a sowbug, aka roly-poly, the size of an ocean-going tramp freighter), and there was heavy intercutting.

Another film, from the same studio and with the same animation style, with a vaguely similar attack robot was [*Castle in the Sky*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_in_the_Sky) -- very loosely based on one of the less-remembers sections of *Gulliver's Travels*, it involves the (long abandoned and ruined) flying city of Laputa, which due to its legendary riches and power has become the goal of both a government agent, of a sort, and a gang of pirates -- and a girl and young man who get caught up in the plot.

The robot(s) of Laputa can *fly*, not hover, but are similar in general shape to the one in *Nausicaa*, albeit much smaller; they also have a weapon (a beam) that shoots from their eye, as I recall.  This film is very memorable due to the broad range of odd flying machines, including a squadron of small ones that look like chariots with dragonfly wings replacing the wheels.

Comment: unfortunately this is not the one as well. I have seen many times Nausicaa. But the style of cartoon itself is somewhat similar to I remember and looking for. I guess at that time this was the "common" style they made cartoons with.

Comment: @kaytrance Actually, the Studio Ghibli "look" wasn't and isn't all that common.  It wasn't common Anime style.  Edit incoming.

Comment: awrr, not Laputa as well, that one is also familiar to me

Comment: @kaytrance Okay, I'm done, then.