# Anime from the 80s that had what I can only describe as giant mech orbs that turned into robots

Tags: story-identification, anime

When I was a kid I used to have a VHS of an anime movie that revolves around the scenario in the title. I have looked at *Orbots*, but the orbs were the bad guys. You had the regular mismatched group: the tall heroic character, the girl, the goofy fat one. The heroes were more like space truckers than your usual type. I seem to remember it ending with this bouncing point that went all over the planet and caused a massive explosion. It was set in a futuristic setting, typical sort of Japanese/Tokyo type city. And I seem to remember there being a chase sequence at the beginning where they were chasing one of these orbs. I also think they had their own giant mecha. This drives me crazy from time to time trying to remember what it was. So if anyone can help I would be grateful.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When were you a kid?  (What years?)

Comment: Part of me wants to suggest [*Time Bokan*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Bokan), but the described archetypes sound more like the villains than the heroes.

Comment: I was born in 81 and we are probably talking late 80s early 90s

Comment: When I say the orbs turned into robots they didn’t combine. They had arms and legs. Like little round bodies with arms n legs. I can’t help feeling like I am making it up in my head, but I swear I watched those VHS way too many times when I was younger. Along with the Last Unicorn and Naussica, although it was called Wind Riders in the UK at the time.

Comment: This could be Birth from 1984. The full movie can be found on YouTube. If so, this question would be a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/79775/108160

Comment: I searched for Birth and wouldn’t you know it! K Mo you are a legend. I knew it as The World of the Talisman I think but wow!! My mind has been eased. I can now die happy. Haha.

Comment: @KMo If you post your answer as an Answer rather than as a comment on the question, the poster can mark it as the accepted Answer, and you can get credit for it.